# How to call out the drawer when I am using Tab navigation to show other screen [react native]

Tags: android, react-native, tabs, navigation-drawer, react-native-tabnavigator

Recently, I am designing an app. And here's the problem when I combine two navigations into one.
How can I open the drawer when the screen is inside tab navigation. Android OS doesn't support a swipe left gesture. Therefore I have to add a menu button for Android users.

Is there any method to call out the drawer?

```
function DrawerNav() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Home"
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabNav} />
      
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function TabNav() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
          flex: 1,
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: "5%",
          left: "5%",
          right: "5%",
          height: win.height * 0.08,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: "#f7f7f7",
          borderRadius: 15,
          ...styles.shadow,
          paddingVertical: "5%",
          paddingHorizontal: "5%",
        },
      }}
    >//Some screen here
      ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNav />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function Feed({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
      >
        <Image
          source={require("./app/assets/menu.png")}
          style={{ position: "absolute", top: 10, width: 40, height: 40 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNav />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use like that you need to put your tab navigation into the drawer navigation it will be available in your all tabs screens. i am using stack navigation but its same for tab navigation
>
> ```js
> import React from 'react';
> import {
>   SafeAreaView,
>   StyleSheet,
>   ScrollView,
>   View,
>   Text,
>   StatusBar,
> } from 'react-native';
> import Home from "./screen/Home" 
> import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
> import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
> import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
> import Search from "./screen/Search"
> import Login from "./screen/Login"
> import SuperRegister from "./screen/SuperRegister"
> import CustomDrawer from "./Components/CustomDrawer"
> import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
> import {MyContextprovider} from"./Context";
> const Stack = createStackNavigator();
> function MyStack(){
>   return (
>       <Stack.Navigator
>       headerMode={false}
>       initialRouteName="Login"
>       >  
>       <Stack.Screen name="SuperRegister" component={SuperRegister} />   
>       <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />  
>       <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />  
>       <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
>       </Stack.Navigator>  
>   );
> }
> const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
> App = () => {
>   return (
>     <NavigationContainer>
>      <Drawer.Navigator
>      drawerContent={(props)=><CustomDrawer {...props} />}
>      >
>       <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MyStack} />      
>       </Drawer.Navigator>
>     </NavigationContainer>
>   );
> }
> export default () => {
>   return (
>     <MyContextprovider>
>       <App />
>     </MyContextprovider>
>   )
> }
> ```

> for open or close drawer you can use

```js
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

for refrains ..[drawer ref..](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/)

Comment: The key point is that I can call out the drawer by swiping  left but the button on another screen doesn’t.